# I want the menu font have a specific color when page is active

Tags: css

I am trying to make the font color of the selected page link in the menu have color #EE4D10. It is supposed to keep that color until navigated to another page. The new page's link should be highlighted then.

Used css code:

```
ul.links {
    margin: 0;
}

ul.links li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 8px 0;
}

ul.links li a, ul.links li a:hover {
    padding: 0 0 0 28px;
    background: transparent url(../images/page.png) no-repeat left center;
    color: #06C4E6;
    text-decoration: underline;
} 

ul.links li a:hover {
    color: #5D5D5D;
    text-decoration: none;
} 

#nav, #nav ul {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 35px;
    font: 115% helvetica;
}

#nav a {
    color: #2F80AF;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#nav li, #nav li.last {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 35px;
}

#nav li.last {
    border-right: 0px;
}

#nav li a, #nav li.last a {
    padding: 9px 0;
    width: 175px;
    text-align: center;  
    height: 15px;
}

#nav li.last a {
    width: 176px;
}

#nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    background: #e3eff7;
    font: 100% arial;
    width: 100%;
    left: -999em;
}

#nav li:hover ul, #nav li li:hover ul, #nav li li li:hover ul, #nav li.sfhover ul, #nav li li.sfhover ul, #nav li li li.sfhover ul {
    left: auto;
}

#nav a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
}

#nav li:hover, #nav li.sfhover {
    background: #00AFD8;
}

#nav li li:hover {
    background: #00AFD8;
}

#nav li li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
}

#nav li li a {
    padding: 10px 43px 10px 43px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

#nav li:hover, #nav li.hover {
    position: static;
}
```

Html used (same on all pages):

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li class="selected"><a href="hypnose.php">Hypnose</a></li>
  <li><a href="toepassing.php">Toepassing</a></li>
  <li><a href="FAQ.php">Veelgestelde vragen</a></li>
  <li><a href="Afspraak.php">Start met veranderen!</a></li>
  <li class="last"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

[The website is here](http://www.hypnosta.nl).
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Just for clarification. What you want, is that when I click nav link (like 'hypnose'), it loads proper page and nav link is made orange. Is that right? But after clicking the other one, you'd want it to go back blue, and make that new link orange?

Comment: Hi Krzysztof. That's exactly what I want.

Comment: CSS has no ability to determine what page you're on, and therefore doesn't 'know' which link should be considered 'active.' Do this server side (with [tag:php], [tag:ruby], [tag:.net], etc...) or client-side, with [tag:javascript].

Answer (score 0):

I see you've got `selected` css class applied to your first `li` element, so you've now only got to exploit that, for example this way:

```
#nav li.selected a
{
    color: #EE4D10;
}
```

Edit:

Of course you'd need a piece of code to ensure the `selected` class is applied to proper `li` element. Meanwhile I've done some reasearch myself, and it is not working yet. It can be done directly in php script, which would be best way to achieve that. Or if for some reason you can't edit the script, you may add some javascript instead to hack it away 'on runtime'.

Comment: I can edit the php file directly. I set the <li class="selected" on every page on the right position and I added the css but its not working yet.

Comment: Of course it's not. It's `a` element (the link) that needs a color adjustment. `li` elements are immune to color atribute. Fixed that. My fault, sorry!